# Submit record from one form to multiple sql tables using one submit button

Tags: java, mysql, swing

I am trying to create a data gathering form using Java (JFrame) in NetBeans. In my form I have two categories of inputs: category 1 (1 TextField, 6 jComboBox, 2 TextBox) and category 2 (85 CheckBox). I want to add both categories in separate tables of same database, by pressing one submit button i.e. category 1 in Table1 and category 2 in Table2.

I am novice to MySQL, help is highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: where exactly do you have problems at?

Comment: @KhalilM , I want to know, how to do it in MySql query using prepared statement?

Comment: Read jdbc library as it allows to use database in java. Tutorial https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first declare your datasource and PreparedStatement :

```
DataSource ds=DataSource.getInstance();
PreparedStatement ste;
```

Later implement some method like this:

```
  public void Add(YourEntity yourEntity){

    try {
        String req = " INSERT INTO table VALUES(?,?,?)"; //depends on how many columns or fields
        ste = ds.getConnection().prepareStatement(req);
        ste.setInt(1,yourEntity.getFirstField());
        ste.setString(2,yourEntity.getSecondField());
        ste.setDouble(3,yourEntity.getThirdField());
        ste.executeUpdate();
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
    ex.printStack();
    }  
}
```